# How to covert int to double in c++

Tags: c++

I want to convert 3 to 3.00. I have done explicit type conversion. but guess it doesn't seem to work!whats wrong?

my code:

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    int PI = 3;
    double a = static_cast<double>(PI);
    cout<<a;


}
```

output: 3

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work?

Comment: Are you aware that `3 == 3.00`?

Comment: @jabaa yes. but i would like to covert to a decimal form with two zeros after it

Comment: you are confusing the value with its representation on your screen. For showing decimal places there are iomanipulators

Comment: That's `cout << PI << ".00";` For this simple task (integer with two zeros after it) you don't even need `iomanip`. `iomanip` is very useful for floating point numbers but overkill for integers.

Comment: @jabaa thanks, but i wanted to use the concept of type coversion.

Comment: The problem is that type conversion doesn't help here. You don't want to change the type/value but the string representation and that's mostly unrelated to the type. Therefore `cout << PI;` (integer) and `cout << a;` (double) print the same string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int PI = 3;
    double a = static_cast<double>(PI);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout <<  std::fixed << a;
}
```